# Is there way to write code usable for both of the multi-processing and single-process in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, code-reuse

The problem is the lock. The multiprocessing needs a lock but not for the single process. For example, consider the following code:

```
Class Test():
    
    def __init__(self, rlock = None):
        self.tlock = rlock

    def do_test(self, invalue):
        with self.tlock:
            return invalue + 1
```

For the multiprocessing, I need to use the tlock but when I use the class for single process, I don't need it. So the line with self.tlock doesn't make sense for a single process execution.

My immediate thought is to write in the following way:

```
def do_test(self, invalue):
    if self.tlock is not None:
        with self.tlock:
           return invalue + 1
    else:
        return invalue + 1
```

But this looks so awkward as I would have handful of methods of this pattern inside the class.

Is there any elegant and efficient way to write the code for the code reuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dummy class that can support context managers, and use that instead of storing the lock if it is `None` (i.e, no multiprocessing is involved):

```
class DummyLock:
    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass


class Test:

    def __init__(self, rlock=None):
        
        self.tlock = rlock
        if self.tlock is None:
            self.tlock = DummyLock()
```

All other methods in the class will not need to be changed unless they are accessing `self.rlock` specific methods (like `self.rlock.acquire()`) instead of using context managers (`with self.rlock:`).